# How to pump data to txt file using Oracle datapump?

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, export, datapump

all hope for you.

I need to export a huge table (900 fields, 1 000 000 strings) in to txt ansi file.
UTL_FILE takes a lot of time. It is not suitable in this task.
I'am trying to use Oracle Datapump, but i can't receive txt file with ansi symbols in it (only 2TTЁ©QRўҐEJЉ•).
Can anybody advice me anything.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle Data Pump can only export in its proprietary binary format.

If you want to export data to text you have only a few options:

1. PL/SQL or Java (stored) procedure which writes a file using UTL_FILE or the Java equivalent api.
2. A program running outside the database that writes to a file. Use whichever language you're comfortable with.
   Pro*C might be a good choice as it is apparently much faster than the UTL_FILE approach, see http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:459020243348
3. Use a special SQL script and run it in SQL*Plus using spooling. This is the "SQL Unloader" approach, see http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#Is_there_a_SQL.2AUnloader_to_download_data_to_a_flat_file.3F

Googling "SQL Unloader" comes up with a few ready-made solutions that you might be able to use directly or modify for your needs.

Comment: It seems I decide the problem as describing in this article  [link](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=425)